# When should I write {} surround a imported thing?

Tags: javascript, import, react-native

Please take a look at these:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
```

As you see, it imports something, but why `React` is out of `{}` and all others are into it? `{Component}` `{ AppRegistry, Text, View }`

Anyway, when should I wrap something into `{}`?

Comment: Perhaps understanding [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) may help

Comment: Check Section 3.3 in [this article](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#having-both-named-exports-and-a-default-export-in-a-module)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in how the file exports, without `{}` is the default export. There can only ever be one default export.

Anything inside the `{}` is part of a named exported function, class, or variable that is exported.

If you look at the react source code you will find the following **es5** code.

```
var ReactComponent = require('./ReactComponent');
...

var React = {
  ...
  Component: ReactComponent,
  ...
}

module.exports = React;
```

When you `import React, { Component }` you are importing all of React 
along with React.Component as Component

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Becomes

```
class Welcome extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

This is commonly used to destructure an object like the following.

```
const person = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
};

const { firstName } = person;
```

Which is the same as

```
person.firstName
```

Answer (score 1):

When you

```
export default MyComponent // import MyComponent
export MyComponent // import { MyComponent }
```